# Insert image within a jQuery Quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded a jQuery quiz online, I was able to edit it but the questions doesn't include images and I would like my quiz to have image questions. The answers option do not need images.

I was thinking I could add it inline in the Questions JavaScript file which is a separate file but it apparently didn't work.

Could someone please point me to how I can include an image in the questions?

Thanks

```
/*--------------------------------------
Questions JS
------------------------------*/

$("#quiz1").dlxQuiz( { 
    quizData: {
        "questions": [{ 
            "q": "When following a large vehicle you should keep well back because this (mark ONE answer)",
            "a": "Allows the driver to see you in the mirrors",

            "options": [
                "Allows you to corner more quickly",
                "Helps the large vehicle to stop more easily",
                "Allows the driver to see you in the mirrors",
                "Helps you to keep out of the wind"
            ]



        },

{ "images": ["../images/image1.png"],
            "q": "You are waiting to come out of a side road. Why should you watch carefully for motorcycles? (Mark one answer.)",
            "a": "Motorcycles are small and hard to see",
            "options": [
                "Motorcycles are usually faster than cars",
                "Police patrols often use motorcycles",
                "Motorcycles are small and hard to see",
                "Motorcycles have right of way"
            ]
        }, ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you narrow it down? Like a small code sample of the issue, rather than large chunk of js?

Comment: I just did. Does this work for you? Thank you

Comment: I wonder who would bother themselves to read this HUGE code dump and why. Read and create a [mcve]

Comment: I am so sorry for the dump, I have minimised the code to exactly the part of the code I need help

Comment: I have sorted it out. The solution is pretty simple actually.

`  "q": "<img src=\"img1.png\"/><br>When following a large vehicle you should keep well back because this (mark ONE answer)",
   "a": "Allows the driver to see you in the mirrors", `

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out. The solution is pretty simple actually. I just needed to add the image tag at the beginning of the question. i.e.

```
    "q": "<img src=\"img1.png\"/><br>When following a large vehicle you should keep well back because this (mark ONE answer)",
```